# IE8 / IE9 does not load CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

On this site http://gaeilge2013.ie/ some stylesheets are not loading in IE9. In Chrome / Firefox / Opera / Safari it's all good. Very strange.

This is the css which is not applying:

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='dzs.timelineslider-css'  href='http://gaeilge2013.ie/wp-content/plugins/dzs-timelineslider/timelineslider/timelineslider.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Link is good. ...

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check loading errors in developer tools?

Comment: Internet explorer have stylesheet limits, but i dont know what means "not loading"

Comment: Some servers may cache css files, therefore if you add timestamps at the end of resources like css files, images etc , they are not able to cache them and always request the new copies

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem you have is due to a limit that IE imposes on the number of stylesheets. IE can only load a maximum of 31 separate CSS files in a single page.

There are plenty of references for this one the web, but [here's one from MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/ad1b6e88-bbfa-4cc4-9e95-3889b82a7c1d/)

This is a hard limit in IE. It is possible to load more CSS files than that by using specific techniques: if you use `@import` to load CSS files from inside others, it is possible to import up to 31 files for each of the 31 main CSS files. But it's not an ideal solution.

In general, it's better to reduce the number of files if possible -- each file that loads is a separate HTTP request, and having large numbers of requests can have a significant impact on page load performance.

My suggestion would be to try to combine the large number of CSS files you have into fewer files. This shouldn't be a difficult task, but there may be WP plugins you could use that would do this for you automatically if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Modernizr for fixing this issue. It is a powerful crossbrowser javascript plugin that fixes all those special cases as for the multiple IE versions as for the rest of the browsers.

I leave you the link here so you can take a look:

http://modernizr.com/docs/#installing